# Changing form color depending on answer

Tags: c#, colors, userform

I have searched, and tried answers. I have the code, but I'm unsure why it isn't working. I am trying to change the backcolor of the form from green back to white. I believe I have it correct, but it doesn't show the first color, only the last.

```
 if (PassBox1.Text == PassBox2.Text)
 {
     this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0);

     // voice.Speak("Correct ", SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFDefault);

     this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(192,192,192);
 }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with userform so I can't give a specific answer. However, what is likely happening is that the background is set to green then back to grey so fast that you can't see the change.

Comment: It may not be that, I added a sleep time to the code, and it goes straight to the grey still. Thanks for the idea though. I'm just starting out.

Comment: The UI of the forms is not changed when you are executing your code but only when control returns to the form engine. So you never see the green color because when you exit from this snippet the background is grey and nothing happens. Adding an Application.DoEvents and a sleep time could get you there but [Application.DoEvents needs to be handled with care](https://blog.codinghorror.com/is-doevents-evil/).

Comment: @Steve Sounds like a reasonable answer to me. Mind posting it as one?

Comment: Nobody should post a DoEvents answer.  Easiest way is to take advantage of the *voice*.  Make it the right one, use SpeechSynthesizer.  Now you can use SpeakAsync().  And use the SpeechCompleted event to change the color back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this code runs and backcolor is set to (0,255,0) which is followed by a blocking operation voice.speak, this does not give chance to the ui to refresh and soon as voice speak is done, the backcolor changes to (192...) before ui gets changes to show the other color.

in this case you would be much happier if you created a subclassed text box which allows you to flash colors. you can use some ideas from this post 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4147406/2903863